# Apache support for single process application (similar to IIS ISAPI)?

Tags: apache-modules

Under Apache, is it possible to run a **single CGI process** that can **handle concurrent requests**?

Using ISAPI, you can have a single multi-threaded process that efficiently handles concurrent requests.  One very obvious benefit to a single application instance is that it can contain a *single cache of data*, for instance; a huge lookup table stored in RAM.

With **FastCGI** (or CGI), **a single exe will only handle a single incoming request**; not concurrent requests.  This means that you'd have to have multiple FastCGI instances running to handle multiple concurrent requests.  This also means that each FastCGI instance would need a copy of the huge lookup table; thus causing concern for **memory consumption (due to duplication)** as well as **time wasted loading each copy of the cached data** for each process.

**[UPDATE]**

After looking at the Apache online documentation, I found that the capability that I asked about in my post above can be accomplished by writing an **Apache Module**.

Apache modules directly hook into the Apache Server but this interface is way too raw (as it should be) to develop a web application as described above.

Assume that a person has experience writing CGI web applications in C or C++.  Running your application as a CGI or a FastCGI application should run fine as a single threaded application in many if not most circumstances.

But if you decide to port your C/C++ web application to run as a module, you will need to build a thread pooled infrastructure for your web application logic to execute under.

Does anyone know of an existing **Apache Module threaded framework** that can be leveraged for developing web applications in C/C++?

Answer (score 0):

FastCGI is not inherently single-threaded. Your FastCGI process can call accept on multiple threads and process them.